# Jquery assign different id to form based on button click dynamically

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a comment form with reply button down to each comments.

reply form has initially `display:none` when the page is loaded, the reply button will trigger to brings up the form (reply_form) when it was clicked:

**reply form:**

```
<div class="reply_form" style="display:none;">

<form role="form" id="reply_form" style="margin-top:20px;">

    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['loggedIn'] ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="list_id" value="<?php echo $list->list_id ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="parent_id" id="parent_id" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name="reply_to" id="reply_to" value=""/>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="rname">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="rname" value="<?php echo $list->first_name.' '.$list->last_name ?>" placeholder="Your name"><span class="error" id="rname_error"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="rcomment">Comment</label>
        <textarea rows="3" class="form-control input-sm" name="rcomment" placeholder="Your comment"></textarea><span class="error" id="rcomment_error"></span>
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btn_reply_comment" data-id=>Reply Comment</button>
</form>

</div>
```

**jquery to show the form while reply button click:**

```
$('body').on('click','.btn_reply',function(){

    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var name = $(this).data('name');

    $("#parent_id").val(id);
    $("#reply_to").val(name);
    $("#reply_form").attr("id",$("#reply_form").attr("id") + id);
    $(".quickReplyForm").hide();

    $(this).after('<div class="quickReplyForm">'+$(".reply_form").html()+'</div>');

});

//reply comment
$('body').on('click','#btn_reply_comment',function(){
    var parameters = $(this).closest('#reply_form').serialize();
    var btn = $(this);
    btn.button('loading')
    //alert(parameters);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'inc/callback/request_reply_comment.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: parameters,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            if(response.success == 'success'){
                $('#reply_form')[0].reset();
                loadComments(list_id);

            }else{
                $('[id$="_error"]').html('');
                $.each(response.error, function(key, value){
                    if(value){
                        $('#' + key + '_error').html(value);
                    }
                });
            }
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log(arguments);
        }
    }).always(function(){
        btn.button('reset')
    });

});
```

**`<div class="quickReplyForm">` block to output reply form:**,

```
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){

    $msg .= '
            <div class="bs-callout bs-callout-info">
                <h5><b>'.$row['name'].'</b> <small>'.date('M d, Y @ h:i A', strtotime($row['date'])).'</small></h5>
                <p>'.$row['comment'].'</p>
                <p><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success btn_reply" data-name="'.$row['name'].'" data-id="'.$row['id'].'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span> Reply</button></p>
                <div class="quickReplyForm"></div>
            </div>';
}
```

my **question** is, how can I assign different id for each of the form by its reply button click dynamically? I can get the data attribute `var id = $(this).data('id');` and assigned into this line `$("#reply_form").attr("id",$("#reply_form").attr("id") + id);` once only.

as shown on the screenshot, how can I give the id to each of the form with `id="reply_form2"` if comment 2 is click, and so on...?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

IDs must always be unique.

Use a custom data value or unique IDs like `form_1 ... form_8`. Then find your elements by using `$('#form_'+yourid)` or `$('.form[data-id='+yourid']')`.

Comment: can you elaborate more on how to deploy it in my codes?

Comment: Which part exactly is giving you trouble?

Comment: my problem is I cannot assign dynamic id into a form's id attribute

Comment: I don't know your whole code, do something like `<div class="reply_form" id="form_<?=$formid?>" style="display:none;">`

Answer (score 0):

When you creating these button, just assign an ID to each button according to the comment ID [look at the ID inside button tag]:

```
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
    $msg .= '<div class="bs-callout bs-callout-info">
             <h5><b>'.$row['name'].'</b> <small>'.date('M d, Y @ h:i A', strtotime($row['date'])).'</small></h5>
            <p>'.$row['comment'].'</p>

            <p><button id="comment-id" type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success btn_reply" data-name="'.$row['name'].'" data-id="'.$row['id'].'">

            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span> Reply</button></p>
            <div class="quickReplyForm"></div>
        </div>';
}
```

Now whenever the click event taking place, just pick the comment ID from the button like bellow:

```
$('body').on('click','#btn_reply_comment',function(){
    var comment_id = $(this).attr('id');
    // Do what ever you want to do with this ID
}
```

Comment: in fact, I can get these unique ID by this `data-id="'.$row['id'].'"`,    my problem is how can I add the unique ID get from the button and assign to form's id as `id="reply_form//follow by unique ID//"`?

Comment: Oo. Got it. Use a hidden text box with every replay button form. The value of the text box will be the Comment ID.
Then send the Comment ID through ajax.
On comment from view Get this taht comment ID and use this as `id="reply_form//follow by unique ID//"`